# Nodejs and async calls to mysql using sequelize block other users

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

this is my first post here, i hope im doing it right.
Im learning nodejs for a proyect i want to do, and im using node to write a web service. i followed a tutorial and got to a working web service, but i had to write the part to connect to the db myself. Problem is, it returns data, but it also blocks everything else.
If query 1 takes 20 seconds, query 2 takes only 3 seconds, and i call query 1 and then query 2, query 2 will only be shown after query 1 is done, blocking all potential users!
Here is part of my code, if you need more just ask

This is one of the request handlers, the last 2 params are for testing.

```
function start(response){
        console.log("Request handler 'insertHood' was called.");
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        var result = db.execute('select x(country_location), y(country_location), country_name, zoom_level from country', response, "Query 1 ", 10);
    }
```

This is the function in the database.js file

```
function execute(query, response, msg, sleepz) {
  var result = sequelize.query(query)
  .success(function(rows)
    {
      sleep(sleepz);
      response.write(msg + JSON.stringify(rows));
      console.log(msg + (new Date()));
      response.end();
    }
  ).error(function(e) {
      console.log("An error occured", e);
      response.write("there was an error man, yo yoy oy");
      response.end();
    }
  );
}
```

I understand that .success and .error are callback functions, but i cant seem to find a way to make them asynchronous, i read about an async library, but i dont think it does what i need, im sure im doing something wrong, what is it?

Comment: `sleep(sleepz)` looks rather fishy...

Comment: Its a function i created to make the queries take more time                       function sleep(milliSeconds) {
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds);
}

Comment: It sounds like a function that is blocking the event loop and causing your problems. Can you post the code for it?

Comment: It's your `sleep()` functions that will be blocking the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sleep` function is the cause of your problems.

When you create busy wait loops in Node, you effectively stop the ability of Node to process any I/O, like accepting new connections, reading/writing files, querying databases, etc.

If you want to delay sending back a response, you need an asynchronous solution. Fortunately, there is [`setTimeout`](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg):

```
.success(function(rows) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    response.write(msg + JSON.stringify(rows));
    console.log(msg + (new Date()));
    response.end();
  }, sleepz); // milliseconds
})
```

Comment: This works! thanks to everyone who helped. So, how can i know that what im doing is not affecting the loop in node?

Comment: @Toddy perhaps [this blog post](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/) is useful in understanding the Node event loop. It even uses something similar to your `sleep` function to explain what the issues with such an approach are.